# Get RecyclerView Item Completely Visible After Restore

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm not quite sure how to ask this so I provided a couple of GIFs for clarification.

**PROBLEM**

[image: PROBLEM]
The first GIF demonstrates the problem I have. When I hit Undo in my `SnackBar` the restored item does not appear in view, but instead I have to scroll up to see it.

**DESIRED OUTCOME**

[image: DESIRED OUTCOME]

In this second GIF the restored item very neatly pops right back into the position it was in before removal. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `onClickListener` of your *Undo* button like this.

```
undo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Restore your elements

        yourAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

        // Get the layout manager of your RecyclerView
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();

        // Scroll to top
        layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0,0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Glad that helped :)